# ODAC Field 'column_name' not found in query columns without alias or table name

Tags: oracle, delphi, odac

Recently we've upgraded our ODAC(Oracle Data Access Components) to version 10.1.5. We started to notice a weird problem. When you execute a query, without specifying the table's name or alias it results in the following error: "Field column_name not found".

Example of working code:

```
select principalimagem.data_inicio from geral.principalimagem
```

Another example of working code:

```
select p.data_inicio from geral.principalimagem p
```

If you remove the table name or the "p" alias, it will result in an error, with the exactly message above.

For some of my clients, internally, It does not result in the error, but if I connect remotely(outside from their local network), it does. I already changed the TNSNames.ora alias to be exactly like theirs, but it did no good. Any clue from what I should look for?
Thanks.

Comment: Really, you **up**graded to a 20 years old version 10.1?

Comment: Its not Oracle version 10, but the Oracle Data Access Component (released on 09-19-17), which is a third-party software made by Devart. Our Oracle version currently in production is 11g (11.2.0.4.0)

Comment: OK, then you may ask the DevArt support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was firewall related. The error was very weird itself, and we had the same error sometimes while writing packages and procedures.

Thanks for the help